# in MS excel find first non n/a value in row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have dates (Jan-2014 in cell A1, Feb-2015 in cell B1 onwards) in Columns in MS Excel. I am using Hlookup to populate revenue data for those dates in row 2. When using Hlookup, I am getting some #n/a due to missing values for some dates. I need an excel formula so that for those #N/As, it picks up the first available value i.e. if there is #N/A in Cell A2 and B2 and 15 in C2 then I need an excel formula to so that 15 appears in A2 and B2 as well

```
A1 B1  C1 D1
N/A N/A 15 16
```

I tried using

`=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(A1,Revenue!$C$4:$JH$306,2,0),INDEX($A2:$DI2,MATCH(1,IF(ISNA($A2:$DI2),0,1),0)))`

But this didnt work. Also, this is array I would preferably like without array.

Comment: If C4:AH4 is in ascending order, doesn't `=HLOOKUP(A1,Revenue!$C$4:$JH$306, 2, TRUE)` work?

Answer (score 3):

With data in **A1** through **L1**, use:

```
=INDEX(A1:L1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A1:L1<>0,),0))
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer! But as `0` might exist, `=INDEX(A1:L1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A1:L1<>"#N/A",),0))` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is your formula in A1, modify it as follows and copy right.

```
=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(A1,Revenue!$C$4:$JH$306,2,0),B2)
```

The issue here is if you copy this lets say to column J and column K is empty, then you will get the value from the empty column K if the value in J is an error).  If you whole row is errors then your whole row will display what is in K.

Comment: thanks a lot, I will try to see if this works in my file